# korbopilko and korbopilkado

Tags: word-difference

Vortaro.net says that *korbopilko* is sport, but reta-vortaro.net says that sport is *korbopilkado*, but *korbopilko* is a ball, used for this sport.  I think the second is clearer variant.  Which meaning should one prefer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same kind of nitpicking applies to football, here is what the [Esperanto wikipedia](https://eo.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Piedpilkado&oldid=6652025) says on *piedpilko* vs. *piedpilkado*

> En Esperanto, oni ofte simple diras piedpilko anstataŭ piedpilkado, malgraŭ ke la vorto piedpilko ankaŭ esprimas la pilkon per kiu oni piedpilkas, sed ĝi streĉas la vortfarajn principojn de Esperanto laŭ la principo de metonimio.

Why should *korbopilko* be any different from that?

A strict distinction between *korbopilko* and *korbopilkado* follows a [prescriptivist path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_prescription) while using *korbopilko* for the sport is more economic and requires less effort (both in amount of syllables and thought while speaking).